# Bash Shell Scripting assigning new variables for output of a grep search

Tags: bash, macos, for-loop, grep

EDIT 2:
I've decided to re-write this in order to better portray my outcome.

I'm currently using this code to output a list of files within various directories:

```
for file in /directoryX/*.txt

do
     grep -rl "Annual Compensation" $file
done
```

The output shows all files that have a certain table I'm trying to extract in a layout like this:

```
txtfile1.txt
txtfile2.txt
txtfile3.txt
```

I have been using this awk command on each individual .txt file to extract the table and then send it to a .csv:

```
awk '/Annual Compensation/{f=1} f{print; if (/<\/TABLE>/) exit}' txtfile1.txt > txtfile1.csv
```

My goal is to find a command that will run my awk command against each file in the list all at once. Thank you to those that have provided suggestions already.

Comment: I am not able to understand your requirement.  What would the CSV files contain?

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand your question. Can you provide more context and more detail, especially about desired output/effect?

Comment: I would first try to use the inverted apostrophes ('\`') in a line such as output=\`grep -rl "Annual Compensation" $file\` and then see what I can do with $output.

Comment: or you can join the 90's and use "modern" command substitution with the syntax `var=$(grep -rl "Annual Compensation" "$file")` ;-) . Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I think what you want to do is add a line after the grep, or instead of the grep, that says:

```
awk '/Annual Compensation/{f=1} f{print; if (/<\/TABLE>/) exit}' $file > ${file}_new.csv
```

When you say `${file}_new.csv`, it expands the `file` variable, then adds the string "_new.csv" to it. That's what you're shooting for, right?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code:

```
for file in /directoryX/*.txt
do
    files+=($(grep -rl "Annual Compensation" $file))
done

for f in "${files[@]}";do
    awk '/Annual Compensation/{f=1} f{print; if (/<\/TABLE>/) exit}' "$f" > "$f"_new.csv
done
```

Alternative code:

```
files+=($(grep -rl "Annual Compensation" /directoryX/*))
for f in "${files[@]}";do
awk '/Annual Compensation/{f=1} f{print; if (/<\/TABLE>/) exit}' "$f" > "$f"_new.csv
```

In both cases, the grep results and awk results are not verified by me - it is  just a copy - paste of your code.